# Calculate new value without converting rows to columns (tidyverse)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a data set that has many observations for a given location. Each observation (defined by a site which has multiple columns of descriptors) contains a measurement (also defined by multiple columns of descriptors). As a pared down example:

```
t<-tibble(loc_name=c('A','A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'),
        loc_desc=c('X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z'),
        qualifier=c(NA, NA, NA, 'U', 'J', NA),
        analyte=rep(c('Clay', 'Silt'),3),
        units=rep('percent',6),
        values=c(0.25, 1, 0.5, 2, 0.75, 3))

  loc_name loc_desc qualifier analyte units   values
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
1 A        X        NA        Clay    percent   0.25
2 A        X        NA        Silt    percent   1   
3 B        Y        NA        Clay    percent   0.5 
4 B        Y        U         Silt    percent   2   
5 C        Z        J         Clay    percent   0.75
6 C        Z        NA        Silt    percent   3
```

In this data, 'loc_name' and 'loc_desc' describe the sample location where silt and clay were each collected. 'qualifier', 'analyte', and 'units' are all information about the 'values'.

What I need to do is calculate a new analyte value, 'Fines' (Clay + Silt). I would pivot the table wider to make this simple, but given the amount of information in the columns, it ends up looking like:

```
 t %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from=analyte, values_from=values)

  loc_name loc_desc qualifier units    Clay  Silt
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 A        X        NA        percent  0.25     1
2 B        Y        NA        percent  0.5     NA
3 B        Y        U         percent NA        2
4 C        Z        J         percent  0.75    NA
5 C        Z        NA        percent NA        3
```

which isn't exactly calculation-friendly.

The end result should look like:

```
  loc_name loc_desc qualifier analyte units   values
  <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
1 A        X        NA        Clay    percent   0.25
2 A        X        NA        Silt    percent   1   
3 A        X        NA        Fines   percent   1.25
4 B        Y        NA        Clay    percent   0.5 
5 B        Y        U         Silt    percent   2   
6 B        Y        NA        Fines   percent   2.5 
7 C        Z        J         Clay    percent   0.75
8 C        Z        NA        Silt    percent   3   
9 C        Z        NA        Fines   percent   3.75
```

Is there a way to do this calculation without combining all of the location-modifying and value-modifying columns? Or if I have to, is there a way to do it that isn't a huge mess (keeping in mind I actually have 19 total columns of information)? The only solution I have right now is to make a whole new tibble in which to calculate 'Fines' for each sample and attach it back as new rows (which I think should work? But it seems inelegant).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a group by `summarise` and then bind the rows with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
t %>% 
   group_by(loc_name, loc_desc, units) %>%
   summarise(analyte = 'Fines', values = sum(values)) %>% 
   bind_rows(t, .) %>%
   arrange(loc_name, loc_desc)
```

Comment: Thank you! For anyone else with the same problem, I wanted to add a quick note. In the case of 'qualifier', this works just fine because the automatically-added NA (upon binding the rows) is correct. If you wanted a non-NA value, you could add it immediately after summarise using 'mutate.' For example, if I wanted the qualifier to read 'calc' for 'Fines' (as this is a calculated value):

`t %>% 
  group_by(loc_name, loc_desc, units) %>%
  summarise(analyte = 'Fines', values = sum(values)) %>% 
  mutate(qualifier='calc') %>%
  bind_rows(t, .) %>%
  arrange(loc_name, loc_desc)`